# One word to describe an approach that eliminate/prune invalid options

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for one adjective to describe an approach, whose distinct characteristic is to enumerate all options and then eliminate the invalid ones. I want to emphasize on the elimination/pruning. I'm thinking of

- An *eliminative* approach (from the verb `eliminate`)
- A *pruning* approach

The options here are the next paths to continue the search procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Other suitable words might be to pare down or to cull. **Pare down** means to remove or eliminate choices, while **cull** means to select or gather for a specific purpose (with the implication that unsuitable choices will be left out) .

A **paring-down**, or a **culling** approach, perhaps. Personally, I think a **pruning approach** sounds the best.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not satisfied with any of the adjectives that could be used with *approach*, something more common is the noun phrase [***process of*** **elimination**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/process%20of%20elimination):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : the act of considering and rejecting each possible choice until only one is left
> // She figured out who he was by (the) *process of elimination*.